# Remove white space from pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have following dataframe

```
     ' A '    'B '    ' C'
0    ' 1 '    ' 2'    '3'
1     '4'     '5 6'   '7'
2     '8'     ' 9 '   '1 0'
```

I want to remove all spaces (`rstrip`,`lstrip`) data frame so that output should be as follows:

```
     'A'    'B'    'C'
0    '1'    '2'    '3'
1    '4'    '5 6'  '7'
2    '8'    '9'    '1 0'
```

I have tried using following things:

```
for col in data.columns:
    print (data[col].str.strip(to_strip=None))

for col in data.columns:
    print (data[col].str.ltrip(to_strip=None))   

data.columns = data.columns.str.replace(' ', '')
```

But no success.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `pd.DataFrame.applymap` to take care of data.  Use `pd.DataFrame.rename` to take care of column names.

```
df.applymap(str.strip).rename(columns=str.strip)

   A    B    C
0  1    2    3
1  4  5 6    7
2  8    9  1 0
```

To account for that little quote guy

```
f = lambda x: "'" + x.strip("'").strip() + "'"
df.applymap(f).rename(columns=f)

   'A'    'B'    'C'
0  '1'    '2'    '3'
1  '4'  '5 6'    '7'
2  '8'    '9'  '1 0'
```

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare I'm assuming your single quote marks are only to show the spaces.  Are those single quote marks actually a part of the string?  Also, 'not working' isn't sufficient information to help you.

Comment: Yup actually its part for data.

Comment: let m e try by removing it.

Comment: @piRSquared perhaps this `df.replace('\s','',regex=True).rename(columns= lambda x : x.replace(' ',''))`

Comment: Yup, actually mine was also working if I remove the `'` from data. Thanks !!

Comment: Hi @Dark!  Actually , think that will get rid of the space in the middle which we want to preserve.

Comment: Oh theres a space in middle too. Din't notice. As always cool answer :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to strip for removing spaces at the beginning and end..

```
import re
sentence = re.sub("^\s+|\s+$", "", sentence, flags=re.UNICODE)
```